# error when I try to open app_dev.php file

Tags: symfony

I install symfony 2 under htdocs(xampp) folder, I start apache then I try to open app_dev.php file using this url :

http://localhost/symfony2/web/app_dev.php

I get this error :

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony2\app/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony2\app\autoload.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony2\app/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony2\app\autoload.php on line 9

the tutorial that I follow ([here](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/vous-avez-dit-symfony2)) say that it will open a page

Comment: You need to install vendors with composer. The command is `php composer install` (but it depends on where you composer file is located)

Comment: thanks for reply i will try to  reinstall with composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reistall symfony using this command :

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.7.*"
```

it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to start symfony via the console to get the development enviroment:

```
bin/console server:run
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#running-the-symfony-application

Also check the read and write privileges, and check the composer installation.